# Can't setup up Windows Server Containers on Windows Server 2016 TP4

Tags: windows, powershell, containers, windows-server-2016

I'm trying to setup up Windows Server Containers on Windows Server 2016 TP4.
I'm following the [guideline](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick_start/inplace_setup) from MS, but it does not work. It always fails with the following error:

```
Getting Container OS image (WindowsServerCore) version 10.0.10586.0 from OneGet (this may take a few minutes)...
C:\Install-ContainerHost.ps1 : Unable to download.
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:1
+ C:\Install-ContainerHost.ps1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Install-ContainerHost.ps1
```

I could find out that the Install-ContainerHost.ps1 script tries to download the WindowsServerCore image from [here](https://pshctnoncdn.blob.core.windows.net/pshctcontainer/CBaseOs_th2_release_10586.0.151029-1700_amd64fre_ServerDatacenterCore_en-us.wim?sv=2015-02-21&sr=b&sig=rLNvGpycEElTr52U6EwrMmnzSRVbsCSIEuO%2B7oa8HYI%3D&st=2015-11-17T22%3A57%3A58Z&se=2016-11-17T22%3A57%3A58Z&sp=r). Calling this URL manually returns "BlobNotFound".

I am not sure if this is some fault from me or they just have a problem with the server. I have tried to run the script already several times today. Yesterday it worked on another VM..

Edit: Seemed to be a problem from Micrsoft with the download server, which was fixed now.

Comment: the same is happenning to us, if I get any further I will get back to you with an answer

Answer (score 1):

OK this is what we did go to your ISO for TP4, and open the ISO.
Inside there's a folder for "NanoServer" in which you can find the wim File (image).

Copy this image locally, or where you prefer on the internet. Get the URL, you're going to use it to hack the Powershell script.
Run these commands in Powershell

```
Install-Package ContainerProvider
```

Verify the Package has been installed by running:

```
Find-ContainerImage
```

*Notepad* Open: C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\ContainerProvider\0.5.2\ContainerProvider\ContainerProvider.psm1

Go to line: 508 and modify the Variable $downloadURL: (notice how I used my own url)

```
$downloadURL = "http://10.0.2.2:8000/NanoServer.wim"
```

After this: Just run

```
Install-ContainerImage -Name NanoServer
```

The image will be installed

Comment: The problem is that i do not have does images anywhere and i can't use the IP from you, because it is a private one. ;)

The problem got already fixed by the guys from Microsoft anyway.

Comment: No, I was trying to make a point how you can spin up a Local Server with the wim. The Wim as I mentioned, its included as part of the TP4 iso. But you're right, they fixed it already!

Comment: Ah well i did overlook this. You are right the NanoServer is already part of the iso, but not the WindowsServerCore, at least as far as I can see.